# Random numbers without duplicates and range between each other

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to get list of non-repetitive random numbers between 0 and 1000, each of which will vary from one another by more than 10. This means that the difference between any selected numbers can't be equal or less than 10.

I want to put some text in svg with x and y coordinates which are not on the same or close position.

```
randomNumbers = [];
// First, pick a bin size b
var b = 40;
// Then generate a random number n0 between 0 and b
var n0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*b);
while(randomNumbers.length < 20){
  // Then generate the next random number n1 between n0 + 10 and n0 + 10 + b
  var minRange = n0 + 10;
  var maxRange = n0 + 10 + b;
  var n1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxRange - minRange) + minRange);
  randomNumbers.push(n1);
  n0 = n1;
  // Continue in this manner until you have as many numbers as you need
}
// If you need them to be in random order, shuffle them after they are generated.
function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  // While there are elements in the array
  while (counter > 0) {
      // Pick a random index
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

      // Decrease counter by 1
      counter--;

      // And swap the last element with it
      let temp = array[counter];
      array[counter] = array[index];
      array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

var shuffledRandomNumbers = shuffle(randomNumbers);
```

Comment: Can you show us this try? Without it, this is a code request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pick a bin size *b* (say, 20). Then generate a random number *n*<sub>0</sub> between 0 and *b*. Then generate the next random number *n*<sub>1</sub> between *n*<sub>0</sub> + 10 and *n*<sub>0</sub> + 10 + *b*. Continue in this manner (using *n*<sub>*i*-1</sub> + 10 and *n*<sub>*i*-1</sub> + 10 + *b* to generate *n*<sub>*i*</sub>) until you have as many numbers as you need or until *n*<sub>*i*</sub> exceeds 1000.

As to picking a bin size, I would pick something so that 1000 / (*b* + 10) is about the number of numbers you need.

If you need them to be in random order, shuffle them after they are generated.

Comment: It sounds good. I will update my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have edited code as I understood your instructions but I get result as: 83,99,104,41,92,56,97,82,71,88,53,111,63,72,84,64,63,83,106,107. Which isn't what I expected. For example: 63 and 64 are too close to each other.

Comment: @N0va- Well, the code you posted isn't even close to what I suggested. At a minimum, you should put `n0 = n1;` at the end of the first `while` loop. That is critical if your numbers are to be separated by at least 10. (I updated my answer to clarify this.) Also, what's the purpose of the `b` array? Just pick a single number `b`.

Comment: Ok last update and now it works. Thanks you are a great teacher. Example result: 128,88,185,467,362,76,314,550,279,518,255,102,37,583,490,164,455,410,212,54